# LINQ Using Single with Try..Catch vs First with Count!=1

Tags: c#, linq, list

What would be the optimal way to get the only element in the list? if it is not equal to one, log it.

Is it better to use a try..catch block against Single? or use Count?

```
try
{
    var item = list.Single();
}
catch(System.InvalidOperationException)
{
    //log
    Console.WriteLine("The collection does not contain exactly one element.");
}
```

or

```
if(list.Count!=1)
{
    //log
    Console.WriteLine("The collection does not contain exactly one element.");
}
var item = list.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Second way is better than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, `try {...} catch {...}` will do *stack trace* and it means *much overhead*.
So the 2nd possibility is a better one (`Count` is a good choice when working with `List<T>`). Actually, you don't need *Linq* at all:

```
  // list.Count is just a integer field, a very cheap comparison 
  if (list.Count != 1) {
    // 0 or many items (not a single one)
    ...
  }
  else {
    // list contains exactly one item 
    var item = list[0]; 
    ...
  }
```

beware *traps* like this:

```
  List<Object> list = new List<Object>() {
    null,
    123
  };

  // item == null even if list has TWO items
  var item = list.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: the `try {...} catch {...}` at least handles the case `list == null`

Comment: @fubo: it's cheaper to test with `if (null == list) {...}`. Usually, `list == null` is a *special case* and should be treated in a special way (if I don't have a list at all...). Better to have an exception: *The list must be, however it's not. Something wrong with my code* that swallow the exception in `try catch`

Answer (score 1):

```
if (list == null || list.Count != 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The collection does not contain exactly one element.");
}
```

As Iridium commented, `Single()` or `SingleOrDefault()` might not be the best choice here because it throws an exception if there is more than one element or the list equals null.

I replaced that with a `null`-check and a comparison with `count`

Comment: It may be worth noting that `SingleOrDefault()` still throws an exception if there is more than one element, however unlike `Single()` it doesn't also throw if there are none.

Answer (score 0):

This way is better

```
if(list.Count!=1)
{
    //log
    Console.WriteLine("The collection does not contain exactly one element.");
}
var item = list.FirstOrDefault();
```